# Issues with creating user profile for a subscriber, but with different profile page and functionalities

Tags: plugins, users, user-registration, profiles

I am building a website where two types of subscribes have to register and get access to a profile page:

1. Volunteer
2. Person in need

I attempted to do so, but the person in need user profile still turned into a "volunteer" account. How can I deal with that? Would it be possible to create a two distinct user profiles with distinct functionalities on Wordpress? What plugins should I use or are there any other solutions ?

Comment: You can only have one user with one email address, so if you were trying to create two separate users - one with each role - with the same email address, that's the problem. However, you could easily create a third custom role that has the capabilities of both. To get much help you'll need to share the code you're using to create the roles.

Comment: I have to clarity some moments. I mean that users can choose only one option when they register - volunteer or person in need. I have added this selection to the registration and tried from two separate emails. However, they are not working properly, because the initially registered as "person in need" account profile gets redirected to a "volunteer" profile.

Comment: There are also two separate profiles for them.

Comment: You'll need to share the code you're using to create the roles and the form in order for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.